# python ctypes C++ get back char* missing last character on linux

Tags: python, c++, linux, ctypes

i have the following C++ code:

```
__declspec(dllimport) char* get_mac()
{
    size_t byteToAlloc = 17;
    char *mac_addr = (char*) malloc(byteToAlloc);
    struct ifreq buffer;
    int s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    strcpy(buffer.ifr_name,"enp0s3");
    if (0 == ioctl(s, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &buffer))
    {
        // Save Mac Address in hex format
        snprintf(mac_addr, byteToAlloc, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
                    (unsigned char) buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[0],
                    (unsigned char) buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[1],
                    (unsigned char) buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[2],
                    (unsigned char) buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[3],
                    (unsigned char) buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[4],
                    (unsigned char) buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[5]);
    }
    close(s);
    return mac_addr;
}
```

which is using ifreq to get the mac address of the local PC and sticks it into a array of chars. 
The routine gets compiled in the "Utility.so"

Then i have the following python code:

```
from ctypes import *
mydll=cdll.LoadLibrary("./Utility.so")
mac_string = c_char_p(mydll.get_mac()).value
print mac_string
```

and i get the following result
02:00:AC:99:00:9

when my MAC is actually: 02:00:AC:99:00:9C

So im' missing the last char.

any idea ?

NOTE: it works fine on both Mac and Windows !

please help.-
greetings.
cp

Comment: your code is C, not C++

Comment: You *must* set `restype` for a function that returns a pointer. The default result type is a 32-bit `c_int`, which will truncate pointers in 64-bit Python. If it happens to work in 64-bit Python, then you got lucky that the address was in the range of a `c_int`. Use `mydll.get_mac.restype = c_char_p`, and get rid of `c_char_p(...).value`.

Comment: @eryksun Then you lose the pointer and can't call `free`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, good catch (of course the OP was already truncating and throwing away the pointer). It still needs to be fixed by setting the result to a pointer type. You can use a subclass of `c_char_p` to avoid the automatic conversion to a Python string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C/C++, c-strings are NULL-terminated, which means the end is marked by a NULL (byte 0).

To store 17 chars of text (the length of the MAC), your array needs to be 18 characters, to account for that final NULL.

snprintf (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) will make sure it can write a NULL, so it is only writing 16 bytes of the MAC, and then the trailing NULL.

In short:

```
size_t byteToAlloc = 18;
```

Comment: Is Python going to know to free that memory, or is an explicit call to another method in the dll to free it required?

Comment: There is nothing magic about python. In python code, python manages the memory so it knows what to free when. In other code, it won't know to free the memory, and would not know how should it want to. This must be taken care of by the interface code.

Comment: I've another method to free the memory in the dll. Just as a matter of curiosity: why on earth the code works on mac and windows ?

Comment: The best option, since the OP is building his own interface module, would be for it to return a PyObject containing a python string. That way, python would handle it properly. And the code would not need ctypes at all.

Comment: Basically, this at the end of get_mac would do the job: `PyObject * result = PyString_FromString(mac_addr); free(mac_addr); return result;`. And change get_mac return type to `PyObject *` ofc.